# Using regex to get cartesian points

Tags: regex

I am trying to draw shapes from a given text file. This file has lots of information, including the vertices for shapes. The format is the following:

1: (0,0), (2,0), (2,1), (1,1), (1,2), (0,2) # 1:(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1); 2:(0,0), (2,0), (0,1); 3:(0,0), (0.5,0), (0.5,2), (0,2)

This line has 4 shapes to be drawn, one starting at (0,0) ... (0,2) then three more past the # sign.

I am looking for a regex which would allow me to extract the x and y coordinates for each vertex of each shape.

Thanks!

Comment: Let's build from whatever it is that you've tried so far but hasn't worked.  Please show what you've tried and then explain how it didn't work.

Comment: `(?<x>\(\s*\K\d*\.?\d+)|(?<y>,\s*\K\d*\.?\d+)` or `(?<x>\d*\.?\d+(?=\s*,))|(?<y>\d*\.?\d+(?=\))`?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU grep's PCRE regexes.

This gives you tab-separated x and y coords for each point, but with no distinction between shapes:

```
echo "$line" | grep -oP '(?<=[(])-?[\d.]+|-?[\d.]+(?=[)])' | paste - -
```

This version adds a blank line between the shapes

```
echo "$line" | grep -oP '(?<=:)[\s\d,.()-]+' | while IFS= read -r shape; do
    echo "$shape" | grep -oP -- '-?[\d.]+' | paste - -
    echo
done
```

```
0       0
2       0
2       1
1       1
1       2
0       2

0       0
1       0
1       1
0       1

0       0
2       0
0       1

0       0
0.5     0
0.5     2
0       2
```